# Disabling and enabling jobs in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, build-process

Currently in order to enable or disable a job, a user must have Job Configure permissions in the Matrix-based security configuration.We would like to be able to manage the enable / disable job permission independently from the job configure permission.
There are some nightly jobs that we want every user to be able to enable and disable the project without touching/breaking the configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provide a script for the users that will do this using the credentials of 'root' user and set only the execute bit on the script so that no one can read/copy it.

At least 3 ways to make a script:

HTTP POST request:

1.

```
curl -X POST http(s)://<your_jenkins_url>/jenkins/job/<nightly-build_job_name>/disable
```

2.

Use python JenkinsAPI.
[Documentation](http://jenkinsapi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using_jenkinsapi.html) is very good, easy to understand much like the API.

3.

The third one can be a script which will use jenkins-cli: accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8663427/4239879) describes this well .

Comment: The curl needs auth: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711696/jenkins-403-no-valid-crumb-was-included-in-the-request

Answer (score 3):

The Job Configure permission is bounded to the disable/enable function in each job, that's true.

One alternative to disable/enable jobs without the corresponding permission is to create new jobs which do this internally. For example, a job that needs job names as parameters, and disables them.

- You could use curl + credentials of a Jenkins user with the Job Configure permission.
- You could use plugins. For example, this script using the [Job DSL Plugin](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#):

  ```
  job("jobname"){
      using("jobname")
      disabled(true)
  }
  ```

For other options, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661349/disable-jenkins-job-from-another-job/).

Answer (score 0):

You may try to [install this plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extra-columns) to get the enable/disable button for the individual project-

[image]

I checked in my Jenkins and I could see this:

[image]

But when I checked under plugins section I don't see this [extra column plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extra-columns) installed. Probably this is the default behavior in latest versions of Jenkins.

Comment: Yeah, I guess they rolled this functionality into the core or as a default plugin at some point. Works for me since around 2017.