# Jenkins: 403 No valid crumb was included in the request

Tags: jenkins, spinnaker

I configured Jenkins in [Spinnaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinnaker_(software)) as follows and setup the Spinnaker pipeline.

```
 jenkins:
    # If you are integrating Jenkins, set its location here using the baseUrl
    # field and provide the username/password credentials.
    # You must also enable the "igor" service listed separately.
    #
    # If you have multiple Jenkins servers, you will need to list
    # them in an igor-local.yml. See jenkins.masters in config/igor.yml.
    #
    # Note that Jenkins is not installed with Spinnaker so you must obtain this
    # on your own if you are interested.
    enabled: ${services.igor.enabled:false}
    defaultMaster:
      name: default
      baseUrl: http://server:8080
      username: spinnaker
      password: password
```

But I am seeing the following error when trying to run the Spinnaker pipeline.

> Exception ( Start Jenkins Job )
> 403 No valid crumb was included in the request

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Finally, this post helped me to do away with the crumb problem, but still securing Jenkins from a [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attack.

[Solution for no-valid crumb included in the request issue](https://linuxacademy.com/community/posts/show/topic/28964-no-valid-crumb-was-included-in-the-request)

Basically, we need to first request for a crumb with authentication and then issue a POST API calls with a crumb as a header along with authentication again.

This is how I did it,

```
curl -v -X GET http://jenkins-url:8080/crumbIssuer/api/json --user <username>:<password>
```

The response was,

```
{
"_class":"hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer",
"crumb":"0db38413bd7ec9e98974f5213f7ead8b",
"crumbRequestField":"Jenkins-Crumb"
}
```

Then the POST API call with the above crumb information in it.

```
curl -X POST http://jenkins-url:8080/job/<job-name>/build --user <username>:<password> -H 'Jenkins-Crumb: 0db38413bd7ec9e98974f5213f7ead8b'
```

Comment: Does the curl statement work with the credential ID instead of the username then password? Thank you

Comment: The crumbIssuer should not be used for scripts anymore, see https://jenkins.io/redirect/crumb-cannot-be-used-for-script

Comment: The `crumbIssuer` CAN still be used, there's just change in behavior - it now requires preservation of session too. Unless you can use the same session between your scripted requests, you must move to a `TOKEN` auth.

Comment: The link in the post is not valid anymore.

Comment: without username and password: `curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8090/configuration-as-code/export' -H "Jenkins-Crumb:$(curl -s -X GET http://localhost:8090/crumbIssuer/api/json | python3 -c 'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)["crumb"])')" -v`

Comment: This almost got me to where I needed to be, but I also needed to set a cookie value that was being returned from the crumb api. Make sure to consume the cookie values and send them as requested.

Answer (score 85):

#### This solution is *safe* to use

We came along this issue when we changed Jenkins to be accessible via a reverse proxy.

There is an option in the "**Configure Global Security**" that "**Enable proxy compatibility**"

This helped with my issue.

[image]

#### Another solution

In the GitHub payload URL, make your URL look like this:
*https://jenkins:8080/github-webhook/*

***Don’t*** forget to mention `/` at the end.

Comment: Just a site note about what I've figured out:
1. Access this site via JENKINS_URL/manage
2. This applies when you use Jenkins behind an nginx proxy.

Answer (score 41):

I solved this by using an API token as a basic authentication password. Here is how:

```
curl -v -X POST http://jenkins-url:8080/job/<job-name>/buildWithParameters?param=value --user <username>:<token>
```

**Note**: To create the API token under the accounts icon → *Configure* → *API Token* → *Add New token*.

Comment: API tokens are preferred instead of crumbs for CSRF protection : from https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/remote-access-api/

Comment: This needs to be way way up. CSRF was not letting me use the token by itself. This answer told me to use --user <username>:<token>. Where were you all my life?

Comment: If using a Jenkins freestyle job, you still need to enable `This project is parameterized` and add at least 1 parameter. Also note the CURL request works without enabling `Trigger builds remotely` because you are using the API Token rather than a CSRF token (crumb).

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Don't inject CSRF headers into API calls or disable CSRF altogether, that's not how anything works.

Answer (score 38):

To resolve this issue I unchecked "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits" in jenkins.com/configureSecurity section and it started working.

[image: Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits]

Comment: Disabling this reduces security of your Jenkins installation, don't do this blindly.

Comment: could you suggest an alternative way that would solve this issue and not create a security risk? @Yorik.sar

Comment: I had the same problem with Jenkins 2.190.1 and I found the solition on [cloudbees site](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/219257077-CSRF-Protection-Explained). It's very important that the request that get the crumb and the one that use this crumb **be in the same session** (use the same session cookie). That's solved my problem

Comment: Santosh answer is much safier.

Comment: You can no longer disable this setting. The check box does not appear in Jenkins v2.303

Answer (score 28):

A crumb is nothing but an access token. Below is the API to get the crumb:

**`https://jenkins.xxx.xxx.xxx/crumbIssuer/api/json`**
// Replace it with your Jenkins URL and make a GET call in your Postman or REST API caller.

This will generate output like:

```
{
    "_class": "hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer",
    "crumb": "ba4742b9d92606f4236456568a",
    "crumbRequestField": "Jenkins-Crumb"
}
```

Below are more details and link related to same:
*[How to request for the crumb issuer for Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738441/how-to-request-for-crumb-issuer-for-jenkins)*

[Jenkins wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/jenkins/remote+access+api).

If you are calling the same via REST API call, checkout the below link where it is explained how to do a REST call using *jenkins-crumb*.

https://blog.dahanne.net/2016/05/17/how-to-update-a-jenkins-job-posting-config-xml/

Example:

```
curl -X POST http://anthony:anthony@localhost:8080/jenkins/job/pof/config.xml --data-binary "@config.xml" -data ".crumb=6bbabc426436b72ec35e5ad4a4344687"
```

Comment: @Balkrishna : Did that work or you are still facing issues ?

Comment: I am trying to configure this with spinnaker. Curl request works but its not working with spinnaker configuration.

Comment: Accessing directly in the browser to `/crumbIssuer/api/json` got me back on track.

Comment: HTTP GET requests to this endpoint fail with a 404 on Jenkins 2.84.

Comment: This is what I needed to make API call from the browser userscript. (for some reason the button to stop a build dissappeared in our UI)

Answer (score 23):

For the new release of Jenkins you should follow the solution below:

From *[Upgrading to Jenkins 2.176.3](https://jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.176/#upgrading-to-jenkins-lts-2-176-3)*:

> Upgrading to Jenkins 2.176.2 Improved CSRF protection
>
> SECURITY-626
>
> CSRF tokens (crumbs) are now only valid for the web session they were
> created in to limit the impact of attackers obtaining them. Scripts
> that obtain a crumb using the /crumbIssuer/api URL will now fail to
> perform actions protected from CSRF unless the scripts retain the web
> session ID in subsequent requests.     Scripts could instead use an API
> token, which has not required a CSRF token (crumb) since Jenkins 2.96.
>
> To disable this improvement you can set the system property
> hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer.EXCLUDE_SESSION_ID to true.
> Alternatively, you can install the Strict Crumb Issuer Plugin which
> provides more options to customize the crumb validation. It allows
> excluding the web session ID from the validation criteria, and instead
> e.g. replacing it with time-based expiration for similar (or even
> better) protection from CSRF

In my case, it helped for the installation of the Strict Crumb Issuer Plugin, rebooting Jenkins and applying a less strict policy for the web interface of Jenkins as it is suggested on the vendor's site.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I also used the Strict Crumb Issuer Plugin to go around this problem.

Comment: I now use the same session to talk to Jenkins after requesting the crumb, which solved the issue. Didn't need to install the plugin.

Comment: This solution worked for me too. For help with creating a System Property, please follow https://medium.com/the-devops-ship/jenkins-use-case-jenkins-startup-script-to-set-the-system-properties-2de8cd1cbe4d

Answer (score 10):

According to [Jenkins Directive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0esgv.png)
First you have to check your Jenkins version if the version is < 2.176.2 then per Jenkins guideline CSRF tokens (crumbs) are now only valid for the web session they were created in to limit the impact of attackers obtaining them. Scripts that obtain a crumb using the /crumbIssuer/api URL will now fail to perform actions protected from CSRF unless the scripts retain the web session ID in subsequent requests.

Alternatively, you can install the Strict Crumb Issuer Plugin which provides more options to customize the crumb validation. It allows excluding the web session ID from the validation criteria, and instead e.g. replacing it with time-based expiration for similar (or even better) protection from CSRF.

Steps :

- you have to installed the plugin called "Strict Crumb Issuer"
- Once installed restart the jenkins service
- got to "Manage Jenkins" --> "Configure Global Security" --> Under CSRF Protection, select "Strict Crumb Issue" from the drop down list --> Click on Advance and uncheck everything but select "Prevent Breach Attack" option. --> Apply and save.
- Now run you crumb script.

It should work now.

[Check this image for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0esgv.png)

Comment: This one fixed my 403 issue

Answer (score 8):

You need a two-step procedure to first get a crumb from the server and then use it.

I am using this Bash script and [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) for that:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# buildme.sh    Runs a build Jenkins build job that requires a crumb
# e.g.
# $ ./buildme.sh 'builderdude:monkey123' 'awesomebuildjob' 'http://paton.example.com:8080'
# Replace with your admin credentials, build job name and Jenkins URL
#
# More background:
# https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/219257077-CSRF-Protection-Explained

USERPASSWORD=$1
JOB=$2
SERVER=$3

# File where web session cookie is saved
COOKIEJAR="$(mktemp)"
CRUMB=$(curl -f -u "$USERPASSWORD" --cookie-jar "$COOKIEJAR" "$SERVER/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,%22:%22,//crumb)")
status=$?
if [[ $status -eq 0 ]] ; then
  curl -f -X POST -u "$USERPASSWORD" --cookie "$COOKIEJAR" -H "$CRUMB" "$SERVER"/job/"$JOB"/build
  status=$?
fi
rm "$COOKIEJAR"
exit $status
```

Here is an example of executing this script with the parameters you need:

```bash
./buildme.sh 'builderdude:monkey123' 'awesomebuildjob'
```

Output:

```
'http://paton.example.com:8080'
```

This script will return an error code if one of the cURL command fails for any reason.

More details can be found from [cloudbees](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/219257077-CSRF-Protection-Explained).

Answer (score 5):

I did get the same "403 No valid crumb was included in request" error when I created a Jenkins job from a Java program using jenkins-client library, i.e., *com.offbytwo.jenkins*. Then I used the Jenkins API token instead of password in the following code. Now, the issue is fixed.

```
JenkinsServer jServer = new JenkinsServer(new URI(jenkins_url), jnkn_username, jnkn_password);
```

We can generate an API token from the Jenkins console. *Profile → Configure* → *API Token (Add new token)*.

The same API token can also be used instead of a password with curl.

```
curl -v -X POST http://jenkins-url:port/job/<job-name>/buildWithParameters?param=value --user <jen_username>:<jenkins_api_token>
```

Comment: Thanks! I replaced password with api token in phabricator post request to jenkins and it helped

Comment: This answer should be IMHO the preffered solution for Jenkins API calls in general.

Answer (score 5):

I lost a bunch of time trying to figure this out. At the end, I just installed the plugin *[Build Authorization Token Root](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-token-root/)* and enabled build permissions to anonymous users.

At the end doesn't really matter, because the Jenkins instance is behind a VPN and I'm using https://smee.io to forward the webhook to the Jenkins instance.

Also the Jenkins instance is behind a reverse proxy, so the "Enable proxy compatibility" option is checked as well, and the "ignore_invalid_headers" setting set to off in the Nginx configuration at the server level. I am sharing my solution just in case someone else is struggling as well. I'm sure there are better ways to do it, but this is one option.

Note that with this plugin the build URL is set to *buildByToken/build?job=JobName&token=TokenValue* and the token is generated in the job settings.

This is in Jenkins 2.235.2 which doesn't have an option to disable CSRF.

Comment: Installing the "Build Authorization Token Root Plugin" in Jenkins solved my problem as well (my phabricator HTTP request could not trigger Jenkins build).

Answer (score 2):

Since this question is the first SO link when searching for "No valid crumb was included in the request" in Google, I think it's worth mentioning that the same error is generated if you omit/forget the Authorization HTTP header or use a blank username/password:

[image: Screenshot showing error with omitted Authorization HTTP header]

Relevant error messages related to the Authorization header are only generated when a value is passed:

[image: Screenshot showing errors related to the Authorization header]

And, yes, the crumb passed in the first screenshots is actually valid; everything works with the correct username/password:

[image: Screenshot showing the crumb used earlier is valid]

So, not sure if that's a bug or not, but "No valid crumb was included in the request" could also mean you accidentally forgot the Authorization header.

Jenkins 2.222.3, Ubuntu Server 20.04, Java Runtime 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1ubuntu1-b09

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to this issue ([Git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to launch a Jenkins job behind a reverse proxy).

1. Get the *crumb* from a first call and store the sessionid in a cookie jar:

   ```
    CRUMB=$(/usr/bin/curl --cookie-jar ./cookie -sX GET https://******.net/crumbIssuer/api/json|cut -d'"' -f8)
   ```
2. Launch the *job*:

   ```
    /usr/bin/curl --cookie ./cookie -X POST https://******.net/job/PROJECTNAME/build -H "Jenkins-Crumb: $CRUMB"
   ```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the below solutions work in [Bitbucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket):

I updated the URL to:

```
http://jenkinsurl:8080/bitbucket-hook/
```

Bitbucket Webhook:

[image: Edit webhook]

Comment: which plugin is that?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while using a GitLab webhook with a Jenkins Multibranch pipeline.

On the GitLab webhook page, I changed the Jenkins job URL base path word **job** to **project**, as I found on in this [link](https://dirask.com/questions/Gitlab-Jenkins-how-to-fix-Error-403-No-valid-crumb-was-included-in-the-request-DWewGj):

> From:  http://127.0.0.1:8080/job/user-test-repo

> To: http://127.0.0.1:8080/project/user-test-repo

Answer (score 0):

For Java code to access the Jenkins API I will let my advise out.

The [answer of Santhosh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60221003/5940655) does resolve the problem. That consists in changing the password for a token, but as far as I know, the token is now a *legacy manner* to do it.
So I tried other way, and find out a solution inside Java code.

Here how I did it.

In my Java code I use the *com.offbytwo.jenkins* package and the class that I use is *JenkinsServer*.

My problem was to create a job in Jenkins because I was getting an error: "*403 No valid crumb was included in request*"

Then I found a Boolean parameter called *crumbFlag* and passed *true* on it and everything worked.

My code was like this:

```
jenkins.createJob(job.getName(), config);
```

Then, I changed for this, and it worked like a charm:

```
jenkins.createJob(job.getName(), config, true);
```

This parameter is inside almost all methods of this package, by example:

- createJob(String jobName, String jobXml, Boolean crumbFlag)
- updateJob(String jobName, String jobXml, boolean crumbFlag)
- renameJob(String oldJobName, String newJobName, Boolean crumbFlag)
- Others.

The technical documentation inside the code is:

> @param crumbFlag `true` to add **crumbIssuer**
> *            `false` otherwise.

I understood if you pass *true* for this parameter it will issue a crumb automatically.

Well, the official documentation has this information in detail. If you wish, take a look here:

*[Class JenkinsServer](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.offbytwo.jenkins/jenkins-client/latest/com/offbytwo/jenkins/JenkinsServer.html)*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to set up a [GitHub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) project with  the *GitHub Pull Request Builder* plugin.

- Here is an example of the response I was getting from my Jenkins server

  [image]
- Response content

  [image]
- The problem was happening because my *payload URL* was missing a forward slash at the end, `/`.
- adding a forward slash at the end of the URL solves the problem
- your payload URL should look like this: *https://jenkins.host.com/ghprbhook/*
- Examples after adding the forward slash

  [image]

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to pass the `X-Forwarded-Host` and `X-Forwarded-Port` headers
as suggested in the [reverse-proxy-configuration-troubleshooting](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/reverse-proxy-configuration-troubleshooting/) chapter of the Handbook.

HaProxy config, inside the `frontend` section:

```
http-request set-header  X-Forwarded-Host  %[hdr(host)]
http-request set-header  X-Forwarded-Port  %[dst_port]
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar problem. I was using a password instead of a *token*.

When updated, it solved my problem. There isn't any need to uncheck anything and make it insecure. Below are the complete steps that I followed to have Jenkins CLI working:

#### Step 1: Prepare environment variables

```
export JENKINS_URL=http://localhost:8080/
export JENKINS_USER=admin
export JENKINS_PASSWORD=b7f04f4efe5ee117912a1.....
export JENKINS_CRUMB=f360....
export FOLDER=test
```

Obtain a token as:
*[How to get the API token for Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466090/how-to-get-the-api-token-for-jenkins)*

Get the *crumb* as:
http://localhost:8080/crumbIssuer/api/json

#### Step 2: Prepare the XML file, file name *creds.xml*

```xml
<com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl>
  <scope>GLOBAL</scope>
  <id>TEST-CLI</id>
  <username>test</username>
  <password>test123</password>
  <description>this secret if created confirms that jenkins-cli is working</description>
</com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl>
```

#### Step 3: POST using [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)

```
curl -X POST -u $JENKINS_USER:$JENKINS_PASSWORD -H "Jenkins-Crumb:${JENKINS_CRUMB}" -H 'content-type:application/xml' -d @creds.xml "$JENKINS_URL/job/$FOLDER/credentials/store/folder/domain/_/createCredentials"
```

Answer (score 0):

Visiting Jenkins with `https://...` instead of `http://...` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was able to bypass the error by using [Remote Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services#Remote_Desktop_Connection) into the Jenkins server directly and using
a [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)-based URL instead of trying to go through the corporate proxy from my computer.

Answer (score 0):

When I was trying to build a job in Jenkins by following options like build steps, accessing Git code, whatever the options, etc., I
faced the error

> jenkins-403-no-valid-crumb-was-included-in-the-request

Seriously, I tried a number of ways to resolve it... But there wasn't any luck...!

Surprisingly, I changed my Wi-Fi network, and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone, from the documentation:
"This message can also appear if you don’t access Jenkins through a reverse proxy: Make sure the Jenkins URL configured in the System Configuration matches the URL you’re using to access Jenkins"

I had checked my nginx reverse proxy configuration, tried the Strict Crumb, but for whatever reason, even when accessing Jenkins using its IP and port, I would have that issue, after updating the URL to be http://: , saving, and then back to the final url, it's working again

Answer (score 0):

I have to just refresh the page . This error can come when the browser tab with oped jenkins configuration turn stale or has been ope for long time.

Answer (score 0):

for setting up [miniOrange saml](https://plugins.jenkins.io/miniorange-saml-sp/)

the 403 missing breadcrumb can happen if the ACS and Saml Audience urls are incorrect, specifically pointed at the `/manage` routes that require authentication.

I had a Jenkins instance auto-configure itself with a baseurl of `https://myjenkins.example.org/manage/` which generated ACS and Audience urls of the incorrect:

`https://myjenkins.example.org/manage/securityRealm/moSamlAuth`

Instead of correct:

`https://myjenkins.example.org/securityRealm/moSamlAuth`

Answer (score -1):

First create a user API token by going to *user* → *API Token* → *Add new token*.

Then use the below script for triggering.

```
import jenkins,requests

job_name='sleep_job'
jenkins_url = "http://10.10.10.294:8080"
auth = ("jenkins","1143e7efc9371dde2e4f312345bec")
request_url = "{0:s}/job/{1:s}/buildWithParameters".format(jenkins_url,
job_name, )
crumb_data = requests.get("{0:s}/crumbIssuer/api/json".format(jenkins_url),
auth=auth, ).json()
headers = {'Jenkins-Crumb': crumb_data['crumb']}
jenkins_job_params={}
jenkins_job_params['NODE_NAME']='10_10_1_29'
jenkins_job_params['SLEEP_TIME']='1h'
response = requests.post(request_url, data=jenkins_job_params, auth=auth, )
response.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: What programming language? [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)?

Answer (score -1):

I followed [this comment](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/2067#issuecomment-407708770): In *Dashboard* → *Manage Jenkins* → *Configure Global Security*. Under *CSRF Protection*, choose option *Enable proxy compatibility*. It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

I saw someguy did on KodeKloud and the webhook link was

```
https://PROJECT_URL/buildByToken/build?job=<job_name>&token=<token_name>
```

. Worked out for me !

Answer (score -2):

Head over to Manage Jenkins => Configure global security.

Then uncheck "**Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits**"

Answer (score -2):

I am running with a reverse proxy with nignx. I changed a Jenkins option in the "Configure Global Security", that "Enable proxy compatibility".

This fixed with my issue.

Answer (score -5):

I have run into the same issue. I have only refreshed my browser, logged back in to Jenkins, did the same process and everything worked.