# Jenkins Github 403 Error

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying to create a new job.  When I select git and enter my repository URL,  I get the error:

> HTTP ERROR 403
>   Problem accessing /job/hello%20world/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig/checkUrl. Reason:
>   No valid crumb was included in the request

I am getting an error in Visual Studio 2013 source control. Any idea on what is happening and how to solve the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins REST API Create job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38137760/jenkins-rest-api-create-job)

Comment: Have a look at this. [http://www.technowise.in/2016/10/fix-no-valid-crumb-was-included-in.html](http://www.technowise.in/2016/10/fix-no-valid-crumb-was-included-in.html)

Comment: I think the problem may be in my git repo because I get error when I try to commit changes in vs 2013

Comment: using vs 2017 I get this error when trying to sync :opening  repositories:
c:\users\user\Source\Repos\*****
Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
cannot spawn askpass: No such file or directory
could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
Pushing to https://github.com/****/hello-world.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from [JENKINS/CSRF+Protection](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/CSRF+Protection).

Check [as in here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API#RemoteaccessAPI-CSRFProtection) that it is activated.
I would not recommend to [desactivate it as show here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44732702/6309).