# Trying to trigger Jenkins build using POST however getting 403

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks, bitbucket-server

Hi I am trying to connect up a Bitbucket webhook connected to a Jenkins server. I have been able to trigger a job using a GET command using a token, however it seems that Bitbucket uses a POST and so I have found a few answers on here about using the following format:

http://jenkins-username:jenkins-password@jenkins-url:5555/job/job-name/build?crumb=crumb_token.

However, when using this I get an Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request

I got the crumb value using this:
https://jenkins.xxx.xxx.xxx/crumbIssuer/api/json

I have also tried the "Enable Proxy compatibility" option in my Jenkins server.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins: 403 No valid crumb was included in the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711696/jenkins-403-no-valid-crumb-was-included-in-the-request)

Comment: No unfortunately I have tried this, and still get the same error. Thanks though!