# Best way to schedule two builds to execute after another (If one executes continuously) in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Best way to schedule two builds to execute after each other (If one executes continuously)?

Example: 
1. Build X run continuously (* * * *)
2. Build Z need to run every 60mins

Is there a way to schedule build Z to run after X even if build x is consultancy running?

Comment: X compiles your application and Z deploys it. You want to make a deployment about every 60 minutes, but you don't want to deploy the same version twice. Is that your scenario?

Comment: @Ishmaeel thanks for the comment, both x and z will execute selenium tests using the browser, Z just runs a specific test which is only needed every 60mins

Comment: Ok, why does Z depend on X? Why simply running it every 60 mins isn't sufficient? Or do you just want to make sure they do not run concurrently?

Comment: @Ishmaeel i dont want them to run concurrently, because will cause issues with my test cases :/

Comment: Gotcha. I can't think of a built-in solution but the accepted answer here seems to fit the bill: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115759/how-can-i-prevent-two-jenkins-projects-builds-from-running-concurrently

Comment: @Ishmaeel thanks i will take look at the Manage Jenkins: Manage Plugins

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Locks+and+Latches+plugin