# How to block a Jenkins job from grabbing an executor in a declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, devops

How can I prevent a job from grabbing an executor if another job (with a specific name) is already running?

I'm looking for something like the [Build Blocker plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin) but for Declarative pipelines.

I've tried the [Lockable Resources plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin) but it doesn't prevent the job from grabbing an executor, the job gets an executor and then waits until the resource frees to actually do anything.

We have hundreds of jobs, so manually configuring each one is impractical and too difficult to maintain.

I've seen these similar questions, but am trying to do this using the relatively new **declarative pipeline**

- [How to prevent certain Jenkins jobs from running simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276272/how-to-prevent-certain-jenkins-jobs-from-running-simultaneously)
- [How can I prevent two Jenkins projects/builds from running concurrently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115759/how-can-i-prevent-two-jenkins-projects-builds-from-running-concurrently)