# JENKINS Builds run parallel and Sequential jobs

Tags: build, jenkins

I have 12 different JOBS in which few of them can run in parallel , but few of them are dependent.

I am using MultiJob plugin and Phasing the jobs , but when one job fails the whole build is marked as failed and to resume i have to run all the steps all over again.

Is there any way to resume the builds from where it failed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give a flow diagram kinda thing so that we can understand better. Just like Job A->Job B->Job C and so on!

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924336/jenkins-parallel-trigger-and-wait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin

You can control you job easily in this way. 
Just crate a controller build flow job, manage and arrange all the job sequence there, the link provided with useful sample and usage, hope this helps :D

Answer (score 4):

this above plugin is deprecated.
you need to use - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin