# Jenkins plugin to queue the jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I need to 2 jobs (JobA and JobB) in Jenkins. If JobA is in run. If I try to run the JobB or again run the JobA while first job is in run state, I want the new jobs to go in a queued state for run.

Which plugin can I use in Jenkins to queue the jobs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent certain Jenkins jobs from running simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276272/how-to-prevent-certain-jenkins-jobs-from-running-simultaneously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two plugins to achieve what you want :

1. [Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin): to block a build of JobA if one is already running
2. [Build Blocker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin): to block a build of JobB if a build of JobA is already running

Comment: I think Build Blocker Plugin can also handle the first scenario.