# Jenkins multiconfiguration project handle concurrent device usage

Tags: testing, mobile, jenkins, calabash

### Case

I have a Jenkins slave witch run's calabash tests on mobile devices (android, ios). To separate on which machines (the mac for iOS or Linux for Android) the tests is run, I also use the **Throttle Concurrent Builds Plug-in**. This way I separate between the Android or Mac Jenkins slaves the devices are hooked to.

I use a mapping table and a self written bash script to call a device by name and execute a test on this specific slave. The mapping table map's the name to the device id (or IP for iOS).

The architecture is as follows:

```
[Master]--(Slave-iOS)---------iPhone6
 |             |--------------iPhone5
 |            
 |--------(Slave-Android)-----HTCOne
               |--------------Nexus
               |--------------G4
```

To hand over the device to the bash script I use the **Jenkins Matrix Project Plugin**, which lets me create a list of devices and test cases like:

```
          HTCOne Nexus G4
Run         x     x     x
Delete      x     x     x
CreateUser  x     x     x
```

Sadly this list can only be executed sequentially. Now I also want to build tests on multiple devices in parallel and cross vice versa.

### Question

> I search for a Jenkins plugin which handles devices allocation. If one trigger needs a specific device it should wait until this one is accessible and the test can be executed. The plugin should integrate with the shell execution in Jenkins.

A big plus would be, if it can be combined with the Matrix Project Plugin!

What I looked into so far:

- Exclusion-Plugin,
- Throttle Concurrent Builds Plug-in, [used to specifiy the slave]
- Locks and Latches plugin, 
  For all the listed ones so far, I don't know how to link them to the matrix configuration and get a device dynamically. I also don't know
  how to get the locked resource information into my script.
- Port Allocator Plugin, not tested but seems to have the same problem
- External Resource Dispatcher, seem to allocate only one resource and is not finding anything if it is a matrix configuration.

Related questions I found, which helped but didn't solved the problem:

- [How to prevent certain Jenkins jobs from running simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276272/how-to-prevent-certain-jenkins-jobs-from-running-simultaneously)
- [Jenkins: group jobs and limit build processors for this group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834677/jenkins-group-jobs-and-limit-build-processors-for-this-group)
- [Jenkins to not allow the same job to run concurrently on the same node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158382/jenkins-to-not-allow-the-same-job-to-run-concurrently-on-the-same-node)
- [How do I ensure that only one of a certain category of job runs at once in Hudson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516883/how-do-i-ensure-that-only-one-of-a-certain-category-of-job-runs-at-once-in-hudson)
- [Disable Jenkins Job from Another Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661349/disable-jenkins-job-from-another-job)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If [Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin) doesn't work as required in your **multi-configuration project**, try 
[Exclusion Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Exclusion-Plugin) with a dynamic resource name, like:   *SEMAPHORE_MATRIX_${NODE_NAME}*

[image]

Then add a Build step "Critical block start" (and an optional "Critical block end" step), which will hold this build block execution until SEMAPHORE_MATRIX_${NODE_NAME} is not in use on any other job, including the current Matrix child jobs.

[image]

*(... Build steps to be run only when SEMAPHORE_MATRIX_${NODE_NAME} is available ...)*